# R.java automatically deletes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I create any project in eclipse, R.java file is automatically generated. But the problem is that after latest adt update R.java file is deleted randomly, and the project can not be compiled. Now I notice that fragment layout and appcompact_v7 automatically created, with each individual project Please help.

Comment: Did you do Help/Check for updates?

Comment: Yes R.java is not a problem but appcompact and fragmentlayout is

Comment: When R is not compiled (and then it's deleted), it's a matter of xml errors (not only in layout files) AND/OR invalid characters in file names (such as UPPER CASE letters or - or other invalid characters).

Comment: what error message you got?

Comment: Remove errors from res folder clean your project that`s all.

Comment: @Vyger That help. I actually did some errors in menu.xml file. So R.java was deleted Thanks Again. Please post the answer in answer section so I can close the question.

Comment: OK, I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When R is not compiled (and then it's deleted), it's a matter of xml errors (not only in layout files) AND/OR invalid characters in file names (such as UPPER CASE letters or - or other invalid characters).

Answer (score 1):

Please check your strings.xml file in res/values folder. If any duplicate ID's exist it will not compile. So R.java will delete automatically.